# Why GNU MP (gmplib) from MSYS2 unexpectadely converts ull to 32 bit integer?

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, mingw-w64, gmp, msys2

I am porting my c++ code from Linux to Windows using MSYS2 (64 bit). The key library is GNU MP (gmplib). The following code gives wrong results in MSYS2/MinGW64 environment while in Ubuntu works fine. Apparantly there is an unwanted conversion from 64 bit integer to 32 bit unteger when using `mpz_set_ui` function.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <gmp.h>  
    int main() {
        std::cout << "GMP version: " << __gmp_version << std::endl;
        std::cout << "GMP_LIMB_BITS: " << GMP_LIMB_BITS << std::endl;
    
        unsigned long long a = UINT64_MAX; 
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    
        mpz_t mpz;
        mpz_init(mpz);
        mpz_set_ui(mpz, a);
    
        unsigned long long b = mpz_get_ui(mpz);
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }
```

Ubuntu correct output:

```
GMP version: 6.2.0
GMP_LIMB_BITS: 64
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
```

MSYS2/MinGW64 unexpected conversion:

```
GMP version: 6.2.1
GMP_LIMB_BITS: 64
18446744073709551615
4294967295
```

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Fresh installation of MSYS2 (64 bit).
2. Steps from `Getting Started` from https://www.msys2.org/ run in MSYS2 environment:

> pacman -Syu
>
> pacman -Su
>
> pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain

3. Compiling in MinGW64 environment using static linking:

> ```
> g++ -MT .o/main.o -MD -MP -MF .d/main.Td -std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o .o/main.o main.cpp
>
> mv -f .d/main.Td .d/main.d
>
> g++ -static -o main .o/main.o -lgmp
> ```

main.d points to C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gmp.h as expected and I verified that C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libgmp.a is used for linking and no other version of gmplib.a is present in subfolders of `C:/msys64`

I also did custom build of GNU MP library using:

> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make install

However the unwanted conversion ramained the same. I probably miss something basic, but I am at a loss.   This is my first question on Stackoverflow and I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: `mpz_get_ui` returns an `unsigned long` so check the `sizeof` that in the two cases.

Comment: Yes, you nailed it. I will have to review all my code before porting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mpz_get_ui()` function returns an `unsigned long`, NOT an `unsigned long long`.

On Linux/GCC, `unsigned long` is a 64-bit value, however the C++ standard only requires that `unsigned long` support values up to `4'294'967'295`, which can be satisfied by a 32-bit integer. Linux allows larger values, but MSVC and MinGW on Windows will use a 32-bit integer for `unsigned long`. This means that on Windows, your 64-bit input value in `mps_set_ui()` is downgraded to a 32-bit value.

Therefore the behavior on both compilers is correct, you've tripped over a platform-specific implementation detail.

If you wish to allow use of 64-bit integers everywhere, you should use fixed bit-width integer types (e.g. `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned long`), but that stil won't allow you to specify 64-bit integers `mp_set_ui` on Windows unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, I was blind for two days long...  There is a workaround as pointed out in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598265/convert-uint64-to-gmp-mpir-number) : `void mpz_set_ull( mpz_t rop, unsigned long long op ) {
   mpz_import(rop, 1, 1, sizeof(op), 0, 0, &op);`
}